# Django: Superuser and user cannot login to admin and user page after making an email login field instead of username

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-2.0

I was looking for the the answer and I still can't find the solution, which works for me.

I am new to Django. I write a web app, which will be basically a blog in which authors are going to have their sites and under each article there will be a comment section. I want that after creation a superuser will be automatically one of the authors. The username field is not necessary, because the authors will be recognized by their first and last names. That is why I need them to log in using just an email.

The Django version that I use is 2.0 and I try to use CBV (Class-Based Views) as much as possible.

After making the username irrelevant and using just email and password in the login page, I am unable to lo login in both cases:
- as the user registered on the website in the website login page
- as the admin registered through the console command createsuperuser on an admin login page

Here is the practical example.

After deleting the whole database and registering a regular user on the webpage and a superuser in the terminal, they are saved correctly in the database. The username field is empty.

`id          username    email                first_name  last_name   is_active   is_staff    is_superuser`

`----------  ----------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------`

`1                       johnsmith@gmail.com  John        Smith       1           0           0`

`2                       mysu@gmail.com       Mysuper     Myuser      1           1           1`

However I cannot login either as a regular user on the website or a superuser in the admin page.

For some the problem that was backend configuration in settings. I followed what is written in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/auth-remote-user/), so the part of my settings file is:

**settings.py**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # to let the superuser login
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
]

# Custom superuser configuration

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
```

My other files are:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class Author(AbstractUser):
    """ Author and User model """

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=False, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=256, verbose_name='email')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        slug_name = self.name()
        slug_number = 0

        while True:
            if slug_number == 0:
                pass
            else:
                slug_name = self.name() + "-" + str(slug_number)
            slug_number += 1
            if not Author.objects.filter(slug=slugify(slug_name)).exists():
                break

        self.slug = slugify(slug_name)

        super(Author, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_app:author_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def name(self):
        """ The function for displaying the name of the author and slugs """
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Article(models.Model):
    """ Article model """

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='articles')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Creates slugs. If slug repeats then adds the number in the i the end
         which has not exist before. Those numbers are in the order """

        slug_name = self.title
        slug_number = 0

        while True:
            if slug_number == 0:
                pass
            else:
                slug_name = self.title + "-" + str(slug_number)
            slug_number += 1
            if not Article.objects.filter(slug=slugify(slug_name)).exists():
                break

        self.slug = slugify(slug_name)

        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_app:detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def updates_detected(self):
        """ Checks whether updates happened. Due to microseconds calculations, it
        is impossible to check it by a regular comparison. Therefore I give the
        article a 1-minute margin. The update, which happened earlier than 1 minute
        from the creation of an article is assumed not to be an update """
        from datetime import timedelta

        d_creation = self.date.replace(tzinfo = None)
        d_update = self.date_updated.replace(tzinfo = None)
        td = timedelta(seconds = 5)

        if abs(d_update - d_creation) < td:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class Comment(models.Model):
    """ Comment model """

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog_app.models import Article, Comment, Author

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from blog_app.models import Author

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView,
                                    UpdateView, DeleteView)
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from blog_app import models
from blog_app.forms import SignUpForm


# Create your views here.

# Main pages
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = models.Article
    ordering = ['-date']
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = "blog_app/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['injectme'] = 'BASIC INJECTION'
        return context

class AboutMeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "blog_app/about_me.html"

# Article views

class ArticlePageView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'article_detail'
    model = models.Article
    template_name = 'blog_app/article_page.html'

class CreateArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:login")
    model = models.Article
    fields = ('title', 'text')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        author = self.request.user
        form.instance.author = author
        return super(CreateArticleView, self).form_valid(form)

class UpdateArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:login")
    model = models.Article
    fields = ('title', 'text')

class ArticleDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:login")
    model = models.Article
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:index")

# Author/user views

class AuthorPageView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'author_detail'
    model = models.Author
    template_name = 'blog_app/author_page.html'

class LoginAuthorView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'blog_app/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:index")

class LogoutAuthorView(LogoutView):
    next_page = reverse_lazy("blog_app:index")

class CreateAuthorView(CreateView):
    model = models.Author
    form_class = SignUpForm

class UpdateAuthorView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:login")
    model = models.Author
    fields = ['first_name']

class AuthorDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:login")
    model = models.Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blog_app:index")
```

Do you know what can supposedly be my problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your custom user model in settings.py using **AUTH_USER_MODEL** settings as documented here : [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) Yes, I have it registered. It is in settings and the code is:

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'blog_app.Author'`
Author is registered in admin.py. After your answer I checked and tried to add UserAdmin as an additional argument in site.register as done the docs - it still does not work.